# Keep Parent Menu Item backcolor when sub menu items are in Hover

Tags: winforms, menu, menuitem, submenu

Using the Code below

```
private class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public MyRenderer() : base(new MyColors()) { }
}

private class MyColors : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color MenuItemSelected
    {
        get { return Color.Black; }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.Black; }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.Black; }
    }
}
```

I achieved this

[image]

Seleceted item of menu gets the black color, Good till here, BUT what happens when I move mouse to a sub menu item? look at the image below

[image]

When I go to a sub menu item I want to keep the parent menu item's backcolor to Black, How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you already discovered the correct property. But if it helps to someone else, you have to set these properties: MenuItemPressedGradientBegin and MenuItemPressedGradientEnd.

Regards.

Comment: I don't know your name @user2498740, but actually I had not found the answer and the question was being dusty in time, and your answer covered it. Thanks a lot and welcome to stackoverflow. Upvoted, happy first points :)